# Google Places API for Android getCurrentPlaces returns empty likelyPlaces with error code 13

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am sure about my API settings and can connect successfully with Google Client API but it seems the Google Places API for Android has some issues, it never returns the likelyhood places along with getCurrentPlace()

```
public void getLikelihoods() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                    .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {

                    Log.v(TAG, likelyPlaces.getStatus().getStatusMessage() + " " + likelyPlaces.getStatus().getStatusCode());


                    for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                        Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                                placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                                placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                    }
                    likelyPlaces.release();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Instead, the status  of

```
Log.v(TAG, likelyPlaces.getStatus().getStatusMessage() + " " + likelyPlaces.getStatus().getStatusCode());
```

returns always ***ERROR 13*** which means it get canceled and I get an empty likelyPlaces

I can run the Google Places Picker or getPlaceById etc.. without any problems. But when it comes to the getCurrentPlace(), I always get this 13 error code

As I said, I am sure about my permission, app settings etc.. 
I am wondering is that a Google thing or am I still missing here something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, the simulators are useless and it works in real device.

Answer (score 0):

There are also various suggested solutions on the sample GitHub issues forum: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/issues/73

Mainly:

- Ensure Google Places API for Android is enabled for the given key
- Ensure Google Maps Android API is enabled for the given key
- Ensure the app is being run on an emulator with Play Store support
- Check running the app on a real device
- Ensure the following code is defined in the manifest:

  ```
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  ```

Additionally, [the docs suggest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#ERROR) that the error code indicates that:

> The operation failed with no more detailed information.